# Как отобразить в ComboBox элемент, которого нет в списке?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Суть вот в чем. Есть список. Часть его значений устарели и не должны выбираться. Но кое где эти устаревшие значения до сих пор используются. Так вот, мне надо, чтобы выбранное давно устаревшее значение отображалось, но в списке его не было.

Comment: Это часть бизнес-логики, а значит, проблему нужно решать не на уровне UI, а на уровне VM. Заведите просто две коллекции, одну актуальную, и другую отображаемую.

Comment: @VladD, да тут не в уровне дело даже, а в особенностях контролов. У ItemsControl есть ItemSource. У них нет DisplayItemsSource и ActualItemsSource. Я понимаю, что без логики в VM тут не обойтись, но и с UI нужно что то поколдовать.

Comment: А вам не нужно ActualItemsSource по идее, разве не так?

Comment: @VladD, я не знаю что вы именно имеете ввиду под ActualItemsSource. Я вполне четко написал что мне нужно. "мне надо, чтобы выбранное давно устаревшее значение отображалось, но в списке его не было."

Comment: Не-не, не дело View знать, что нужно отображать, если этой информации не приходит из VM. Правильный ответ у @dm.dymov: VM должно поставлять как информацию об элементах, так и информацию о том, должно ли быть возможно выбрать этот элемент.

Comment: @VladD, View и не должна знать. Она должна только правильно реагировать на то, что лежит в ВМ. Я в итоге нашел решение самостоятельно, но в части View оно похоже на способ предложенный в ответе. Я там коммент оставил, если интересно

Comment: Ага, спасибо, прочитал, да, по идее так и надо.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно использовать [`CompositeCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) - коллекцию, предназначенную для объединения нескольких коллекций (поддерживает `INotifyCollectionChanged`).

Пример:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>() { "New value 1", "New value 2", "New value 3" };
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
        xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Values"
                              Source="{Binding Values}" />
        <data:CompositeCollection x:Key="CompositeValues">
            <sys:String>Old value</sys:String>
            <data:CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Values}}" />
        </data:CompositeCollection>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource CompositeValues}" />
</Window>
```

В результате в `ComboBox` получим список из 4 значений, начинающийся с `OldValue`.

На самом деле @VladD прав и лучше всё это решить на уровне VM.

**UPD** Чтобы значение изначально было выбрано в `ComboBox`, оно должно присутствовать в списке его элементов. Однако, если нужно, чтобы его нельзя было выбрать, его можно заблокировать и/или сделать невидимым. Например, через стиль контейнера элемента:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource CompositeValues}"
          SelectedItem="Old value">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }"
                             Value="Old value">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                            Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Я ведь написал, что старого значения не должно быть в списке, чтобы его нельзя было выбрать. Оно просто должно отображаться изначально, так как оно уже установлено.

Comment: @iRumba, чтобы оно отображалось изначально, оно должно быть в списке. Однако его можно заблокировать для выбора.

Comment: @iRumba, обновил ответ.

Comment: Поправки. Способ не совсем корректный в плане исполнения. Его может быть сложно затачивать под конкретные задачи. Я в результате сделал  через дополнительное свойство в айтеме в ВМ IsActual. По поводу ItemContainerStyle, я изначально пытался сделать иначе. Я играл со свойством Visibility. В итоге в списке элемента видно не было, но стрелочками можно было выбрать невидимый элемент :) А вот если добавить еще и сеттер на IsEnabled, то все норм становится. То есть в ваш способ надо добавить сеттер на Visibility. Подправьте ваш ответ, пожалуйста, и я тыкну в галочку

Comment: @iRumba, сделал.

Comment: Не совсем. Я бы отказался тут от от CompositeCollection в пользу свойства IsActual у ItemVM. Просто потому, что такой подход будет более универсальным, нежели добавление элемента к коллекции. В конце концов конструктор Item не обязательно будет без аргументов, а в этом случае его не создать через xaml. Поэтому я предлагаю в качестве ItemsSource использовать коллекцию из VM, в которой есть все доступные элементы, но те, что будут отображаться будут иметь IsActual == true. И в триггере будет проверяться именно это свойство

Comment: @iRumba, мой изначальный посыл был насчет CompositeCollection, решение с VM очевидное, но я не стал его расписывать. Так что можете оформить свой собственный ответ, думаю, это будет честно.

Comment: @iRumba, к слову говоря, не обязательно ничего создавать в xaml, строка в примере только для примера, подразумевалось, что при необходимости с VM будет затягиваться вторая коллекция старых неиспользуемых значений, которая будет входить в композит через второй коллекшнконтейнер. Блочить ее значения можно через стиль точно так же, при использовании конвертера, или через itemcontainerstyleselector.

Comment: Блочить ничего не нужно. Если я заблочу устаревшие значения, то в ComboBox вообще ничего отображаться не будет. Поэтому тут не нужно объединение коллекций просто исходя из задачи, которую я поставил. Тут нужна актуальная коллекция + один единственный айтем, который является текущим значением, но может не быть актуальным.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57874/discussion-between-dm-dymov-and-irumba).